# Restarting PC's and writing to the event log with a custom message

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-log, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have written a script in PowerShell that will remotely restart a list of PC's using the 'Restart-Computer' command.

Is there a way of adding a custom message to the systems event log, to explain that the computer has been restart by my script.

Comment: have you tried write-eventLog? Syntax available if you type get-help write-eventlog you'll see the syntax?

Comment: I have looked into this option, I was just wondering whether there was a way of over riding the default event entry that would still appear after the restart. Mean you would have 2 restart messages in the event log (the default and the custom)

Comment: And using the `shutdown` command with the -c (comment) parameter?

Comment: Thanks that has seemed  to do the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell code that I used to solve this problem as suggested by the user [C.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520612/c-b) above.

`Shutdown /r /f /m ComputerName /d P:0:1 /c "Your comment"`

This code will force (/f) a shut down and reboot (/r) of a given PC and write to the event log with a custom comment (/c). **Note** that to write a custom comment a reason code will need to be supplied using the (/d) parameter. Also note that the order of parameters matters.

For a list of reason codes and syntax follow the links below.

- http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html
- [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Very useful.  Just a tweak - should be `/m \\ComputerName`